# php multiple email targets won't work

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

I'm trying to get this to send the form information to multiple e-mails but for some reason it only sends to whichever e-mail is listed first in the $mail->address field. Can anyone help?

```
if(empty($errors)) {

        require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = '192.168.555.555';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->Username = '';
        $mail->Password = '';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = '';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->From = 'donotreply@website.com';
        $mail->FromName = $from;
        $mail->addAddress('email1@email.com' , 'email2@email.com');
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Employment Application';
        $mail->Body    = $message;

        if($mail->send()) {
            //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $success = '<div class="alert alert-success"><h3 style="margin:0">Message Sent!</h3></div>';
        }

    }
```

Comment: loop email addresses from db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addAddress()` method only accept one email address and the name of the recipient that is optional. You can add multiple `addAddress()` method to send the same message to multiple email address like the following:

```
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');
$mail->addAddress('john@example.com', 'John Doe');
```

Alternatively, a better way would be to send carbon copy. You can send the carbon copy by using the following method:

```
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
```

If you like you can also use BCC:

```
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

The method addAddress accepts one email address at a time. The second parameter is optional.

```
public function addAddress($address, $name = '')
{
    return $this->addAnAddress('to', $address, $name);
}
```